# Google maps v3 zoom animation not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Not sure why this question was closed - it seems fairly focused to me:  "mousewheel zooming in and out in our maps v3 application does not show the red animated corners during the zoom operation as it does in our maps v2 version. Is there a specific option required to enable this animation in maps v3? tia."

I'll add the following to dissolve any ambiguity regarding the question:

When using Google Maps v3 through the browser, during a zoom operation using the mousewheel, a red frame comprised of only the corners of the frame is drawn to the screen.

I am using Maps V3 via a WebBrowser control in a winforms application.

Mousewheel zooming in my application does not generate this same red frame.

my maps v3 options are as follows:

```
var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
    zoom: zoomLevel,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 19,
    overviewMapControl: true,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: false
};
 //create the map
_map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
```

I'd like to know if there is a specific option that I should add (or there is something else I could do) to allow generation of this frame during the zoom operation.  Google Maps documentation yields nothing.

Comment: I doubt this "feature" is around in V3. Here's a jsfiddle with your options http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/581/ Most likely you'll have to hack together something that captures a zoomChange event.

Comment: Wheres the red frame...